Why can't I install any package for my React app after the first time?
When I try to install anything like
npm install gh-pages --save-dev

I got that error
npm error code EISDIR
npm error syscall symlink
npm error path E:\Projects\React Js\Netflix Clone Project
npm error dest E:\Projects\React Js\Netflix Clone Project\node_modules\app-netflix-clone
npm error errno -4068
npm error EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'E:\Projects\React Js\Netflix Clone Project' -> 'E:\Projects\React Js\Netflix Clone Project\node_modules\app-netflix-clone'

I don't know what to do.
I tried to make the name of the project different than the app name but nothing changed.

Not really sure in what kind of scenario npm would attempt to symlink a package folder to a dependency inside the package's node_modules. Can you share your project source or provide a [mre] to help others reproduce the issue?
